# kubectl get with template string fails with incompatible types for comparison

Tags: go, kubernetes, go-templates

I have to check if my application container in a replication controller runs on a certain port. Here is the command with the go template string that I'm using.

```
kubectl get rc my-rc --namespace=nightly --template='{{range .spec.template.spec.containers}}{{if .ports}}{{range .ports}}{{if .containerPort}}{{if eq .containerPort 5445}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

I think it is not a string comparison since it is a port. even string comparison throws an error "error calling eq: incompatible types for comparison'"

I could just fetch an array of container ports and do the comparison outside but want to get it done inside the go template.

I am new to Go lang. Appreciate any suggestions to accomplish this using template string or using a template file.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspecting the .containerPort with `printf "%T" .containerPort` shows that it's a float64. if you compare your port with a trailing `5445.0` it should work.

You also have some unnecessary if statements.

```
--template='{{range .spec.template.spec.containers}}{{range .ports}}{{if eq .containerPort 5445.0}}True{{end}}{{end}}{{end}}'
```

Your example was also missing the `-o="go-template"` flag to specify the output as a Go template.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I did figure that it was a floating representation and tested it as you've shown but forgot to output a string. I do need the if statement because i've data containers that do not have a ports array and want to avoid errors.

Comment: range should be okay with undefined vars. You can test it by replacing `.ports` with `.foo`